# Devise user_root_path gets 404'd in production but not dev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

weird, i know but using `user_root_path` in production does not work.  When i click on the link `myapp.com/user` i get a 404 page.

The log file doesn't show spit but a failed attempt:

```
Started GET "/user" for 123.125.146.23 at 2011-01-19 19:40:45 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant User::UsersController):
```

Now the only way to see something about this unitialized constant is to turn on `rails c` and type the constant into the console.  Here is what happens:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005 > User::UsersController
(irb):5: warning: toplevel constant UsersController referenced by User::UsersController
=> UsersController
```

Now some digging found that this toplevel warning could be messing with it. But the log says bubkiss.

So i changed the route file from:

```
  devise_for :users
namespace :user do
  root :to => "users#index"
end
resources :subdomains
match '/user' => 'users#index'
```

to:

```
devise_for :users
namespace :user do
  root :to => "subdomains#index"
end
resources :subdomains
match '/user' => 'users#index', :controller => :users
```

The thought was that maybe production environment did not like a user#index... so i changed it to subdomains#index.  I can get /subdomains no problem. so the actual page will show, it's the route that is fudged... any thoughts?

setup: rails 3.0.3, devise 1.1.5 (and was 1.1.3 upgraded, same problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
devise_for :users do
   match 'user' => "users#index", :as => :user_root, :constraints => { :domain => SITE_DOMAIN}
end
```

In each of your development.rb or production.rb files you would have a SITE_DOMAIN constant so like:

```
::SITE_DOMAIN = "lvh.me" 
#in development.rb I was using subdomains with the helpful lvh.me google it.
```

or in production.rb

```
::SITE_DOMAIN = "mydomain.com"
```

Again i needed subdomains, so this worked for me.

The devise wiki did not work for me.  Once i have time i will update that too, or submit a ticket, but this is just google juice for those that need it.

Comment: does this work on both local dev and production (I am using heroku)...I tried the wiki and it did not work.

Comment: I edited the answer above to work in both dev and production.

Comment: ah, okay I will try this...in development I am just using localhost:3000 so i assume I use that?  Isn't there a built in Rails command that knows the domain?  Thanks....frustrating that the wiki is wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are namespacing your routes, you need to namespace your controllers as well.

Move controllers/users_controller.rb to controllers/user/users_controller.rb and edit it to add in the module:

```
class User::UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```

But my guess is you aren't actually meaning to use namespace in the route.

Comment: no dice. I mean i think I'm following the readme, as well as i can figure.  Do you use a root_path with devise? if so holler back.

Comment: I don't know those things. I was just explaining how Rails uses Ruby namespacing. Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with /user giving a 404 in production. Here is the solution I ended up with which I think is simpler than messing with the routes. In ApplicationController put:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  stored_location_for(:user) || landing_welcome_path
end
```

Can someone explain how the environment affects routing in rails 3?

Comment: did this end up working?  can I use the paths found in rake routes in the landing_welcome_path?