# My new password page says 404 in production mode only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano

http://site.com/users/password/new is returning a 404 in production mode but not in development.  I am deploying via capistrano and it looks like it's copying the entire site over properly.  I tried running the console in production mode on the server and couldn't find anything.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What does production.log say?

Comment: use `rake routes` to know what are your routes and to see if `/users/password/new` is available.

Comment: @FernandoAlmeida, yeah all the routes are there as they should be. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this path works in development and fails in production I would focus on the differences between your environments.

A common issue is that people commit their changes locally, but do not push them to (e.g.) GitHub before deploying with capistrano. Can you ssh into your server and go to the current path and run `rake routes` there? Try and check if there are differences.

Once you've confirmed that at least the routes on the server are up to date, try checking the production log while accessing /user/password/new. It should be in /shared/log/production.log. You could ssh there and use `tail -f production.log` to follow the log while you try to access the path.

On a side note, it seems that you are using Devise. There have been similar issues for the user root path. See for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741490/devise-user-root-path-gets-404d-in-production-but-not-dev). Perhaps this will shed some light on your problem.